# Python: Background timer to exit code (on Windows)

Tags: python, timer, constraints, constraint-programming, or-tools

I'm in the process of finishing my very first constraint programming assignment on Python. At some high scale problems code gets stuck and computes the optimal solution for ages, so I want to create a background timer that would exit the program (most likely as an except) and pick previous optimal solution. I've tried "signal" module before - didn't work out on Windows.

This one also didn't work out as I presume it practically not getting out of the loop to check the condition.

```
start = time.time()
while time.time - start < 60
```

Here's the code and want to get out from:
At some point it gets stuck at `status = solver.Solve(model)` so I presume I need some kind of timer, external from this loop to pull me out of the code. Maybe something async?

```
...

    with open(file_location, 'r') as input_data_file:
    input_data = input_data_file.read()
# Modify this code to run your optimization algorithm

    # parse the input
    lines = input_data.split('\n')

    first_line = lines[0].split()
    node_count = int(first_line[0])
    edge_count = int(first_line[1])

    edges = []

    for i in range(1, edge_count + 1):
        line = lines[i]
        parts = line.split()
        edges.append((int(parts[0]), int(parts[1])))

    # build a trivial solution
    # every node has its own color
    
    k = 20
   
    while True:
        
        model = cp_model.CpModel()
        nodes = []
        for i in range(0, node_count):
            i = model.NewIntVar(0,k, "node %i" % i)
            nodes.append(i)
        for i, conn in enumerate(edges):
            model.Add(nodes[conn[0]] != nodes[conn[1]])

        solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
        solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 8
        finish_time = time.time() + solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds
        solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8
        
        solution_printer = VarArraySolutionPrinter(nodes)
        status = solver.SolveWithSolutionCallback(model, solution_printer)
        solution = []

        if time.time() >= finish_time:
            print("We die!")
            break

        if status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
            print('Solution is FEASIBLE \n\n\n')
            print("Colors Used: %i" % k )
            k = k - 1
            continue

        if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
            print('Solution is OPTIMAL ')
            print("Colors Used: %i \n\n\n" % k )
            k = k - 1
            continue

        #CATCHING THE FINAL SOLUTION
        if status == cp_model.INFEASIBLE:
            k = k + 1
            model = cp_model.CpModel()
            nodes = []

            for i in range(0, node_count):
                i = model.NewIntVar(0,k, "node %i" % i)
                nodes.append(i)

            for i, conn in enumerate(edges):
                model.Add(nodes[conn[0]] != nodes[conn[1]])

            solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
            solution_printer = VarArraySolutionPrinter(nodes)
            status = solver.SolveWithSolutionCallback(model, solution_printer)
            solution = []
            checker_var = 1

            print("This is optimal solution." + " Number of colors: %i" % k)
            for i in nodes:
                i = solver.Value(i)
                solution.append(i)
            break
...
```

Just edited the code with `parameters` , for some reason still stuck

Thanks for all help, it finally works and throws me out of that loop!

Comment: why not just `solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 60`? and don't forget to use more than 1 core with `solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8`

Comment: I've added ` solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 60` and  `solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8 `
They're working, but for some reason, program still gets stuck and I cant even get the core reason for that. It just stops running.
` 
if time.time() >= finish_time:
print("We win!")
break  `
also didn't work out...
I also tried looking up that `parameters` in cp_module to check the documentation but couldn't find any mention of it

Comment: You set up finish_time before you define max_time_in_seconds

Comment: Yes! That was embracing. It's going out of that loop now finally! Thanx so much for help